# Stop Environment path expansion in visual studio define

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I am using program that auto generates visual studio project files. In these generated projects I would like to have a #define that specifies a configuration file path.This will allow me to not change the code when a path has to change. In this path I need to be able to use a environment path such as

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\\\\Company\\\\Config.cfg.
```

This environment variable must exist at **runtime**. In my preprocessor list I have:

```
CONFIGURATION_PATH="%LOCALAPPDATA%\\\\Company\\\\Config.cfg".
```

Unfortunately upon use it changes to:

`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\\Company\\Config.cfg.`

This means that it compiles with the expanded path. If a new user runs the program the path will be wrong. Is there anyway I can stop visual studio from expanding the environment variable when the preprocessor runs?

Is there any other solutions to this problem that people can think of?

Comment: Consider passing the path as a parameter to the program.  Or, storing it in a file (xml?) to be read by the program.

Comment: It is being used inside many other programs so that may not be the best solution. Also storing a configuration file path inside a file defeats the purpose as I would then need the path to that file.

Comment: You need to escape your % characters. Try %% or ^%.

Comment: @n.m. but then will I be able to call ExpandEnvironmentPath on them in c++ to get the runtime value? Or will I have to modify the string to get it back to the correct version?

Comment: Try it. See what you get.

Comment: Did not seem to expand correctly with either.

Comment: *Did not seem to expand correctly*. How do you know? What does it turn to in the source? Can you print what is being fed to `ExpandEnvironmentPath`?

Comment: I look at the result of the command? Either expands to %C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local% or ^%LOCALAPPDATA^%.

Comment: If your program that generates your project files behaves like that, I'm afraid you need to change it, or perhaps read its manual if it has one.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the program that generates the project files. The project file is generated correctly. The macro is being expanded by visual studio. ExpandEnvironmentPath is being called by c++ in the generated project. Maybe I should have just left that part out of the question.

Comment: *Maybe I should have just left that part out of the question* Yes, pretty much so. Please have a **minimal** question. In its current state is confusing and misleading. Also please bear in mind that I'm not getting any notifications when you post your comments. I have a habit of checking back my old comments sometimes, but not always. Thank you.

Comment: I think you want to try [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2005/11/04/how-to-escape-the-percent-sign-in-msbuild/).

Comment: @n.m. That looks perfect, if you make that an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx), the way to escape special characters in msbuild is the `%XX`, where XX is the hexadecimal equivalent of the character. (This is sometimes called "URL-encoding"). Thus, in order to use the percent character literally, you have to encode it as `%25`. An environment variable name `%LOCALAPPDATA%` becomes `%25LOCALAPPDATA%25` etc.